# SQLite, how to entities associations without foreign keys?

Tags: database, sqlite

I am trying to figure out the way of creating table without a foreign key under sqlite. I would like to avoid the use of foreign key due its incompatibility under some applications I am working now.

Could anyone please show a simple example with maybe two tables? Thank you.

Simple example: How do I select all tracks from one specific artist?

```
CREATE TABLE artist(
  artistid    INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
  artistname  TEXT
);

CREATE TABLE track(
  trackid     INTEGER, 
  trackname   TEXT, 
  trackartist INTEGER
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't specify a foreign key, then there is no foreign key.

```
SELECT t.trackname, t.trackid
  FROM track t
 INNER JOIN artist a
    ON a.artistid = t.trackartist
 WHERE a.artistname = 'Alex'
```

Comment: yes, but how to make associations between table entities? In order to make calls something like (SELECT 1 FROM artist WHERE artistid=trackartist)

Comment: @Alex: foreign keys are only constraints. Not having the constraint does not imply that you have to change your queries.

Comment: I made an update to my post. What query do I need to make to select all tracks from one specific artist without using a foreign key?

Comment: Thank you! Can you explain why you are using T. A. is that some kind of shortcode or its just a first letter of the table?

Comment: @Alex: it is called an alias and you can choose it! I advise you to read a simple book on SQL basics, you will learn many things.

Answer (score 4):

You can have relationships between tables without declaring a foreign key.  You simply do

```
SELECT a.*, t.* FROM artist a INNER JOIN track t ON a.artistid = t.trackartist;
```

(substituting the actual columns you want in place of `a.*, t.*`).

You can do this without declaring that trackartist is a foreign key to artist(artistid).  If you do make that declaration, the difference is that SQLite will ensure that you never put a value in trackartist that is not a valid artistid and that you never change or remove an artistid that is used in trackartist.

Foreign keys are a mechanism to maintain the integrity of the association between tables but you can "create" any association you want in a SELECT statement independent of any primary or foreign keys declared in the database.